# Is it possible to have temporary/conditional permissions on files in perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce, file-permissions, bug-tracker

The problem i am trying to solve is where developers change files without going through the proper channels. The developer should be able to make the change himself but only after his work was approved, since the code is used in a lot of projects

I found this link that also describes my problem:
http://www.p4ideax.com/ideas/694/temporary-permissions

One way to do it is to have only the architects have access to the files and then granting the developer temporary access. Maybe the permission can be linked to a specific job in perforce. The only way i can see how to do that is by adding the files that the person should be able to change to a new field in the jobs template ( done by architect ). Then have a server app dynamically call p4 protect and manage the permissions table. Then when the job is closed the permission is revoked. The server app could be the bugtracker software.

Is there an easier way or even 3rd party software out there that can solve the problem?

I know that another way to solve it is to put these sensitive files in a branch and then only allow the architects permission to merge into this branch. This solution feels a bit heavy handed.

Any suggestions would be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

This is something that could certainly be done with a pre-submit hook.   There are examples at [Perforce Depot](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/Pre-Submit_Trigger_Examples).

My thinking would be to reject submits for files in that section of the depot that didn't have a job that was on the "approved list".   You could create the approved list in a number of ways, although a simple one (if you're using Perforce globally) would be to put the job list into a file under repository control and then have that list be available only to the architects.

The pre-submit trigger would then basically need to:
- If the files being submitted aren't in the protected tree, let the submit happen
- Grab an r/o copy of the file from the depot
- Grab the job list from the submit
- grep the job against the list
- If the job is in the list, let the submit happen
- Reject the submit with an appropriate error message